# Web pages graph data sets

Tags: data-request, metadata, network-structure

Is anyone aware of any web graph datasets, such that the nodes represent the webpages and the link represent the URLS? I am looking for a dataset which has node attributes. I have found many datasets, but not sure if they have provided the node attributes (as I'm new to Graph Theory).
The node attributes should basically represent the features of the web pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The WDC12 page-level graph should be useful. The full graph is extremely large, though, and will need hefty computing resources to work with. More details at http://www.webdatacommons.org/hyperlinkgraph/index.html